# Applicability of two or more exception types at the same time

Tags: java, exception

Suppose I design a method that computes the `arcsin` function. Of course, only numbers in the closed interval [-1,1] are acceptable as arguments to the function.

If, however, a number outside that interval is passed, the method throws an exception. My question is, are `IllegalArgumentException` and `ArithmeticException` both equally applicable? If yes, cite some more examples of cases where two or more exception types are equally applicable. If not, why?

Comment: `Math.asin` returns `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, it's possible to raise one type of exception at a time.

It's possible to nest exceptions (by wrapping one exception around another -- see the `cause` argument as part of the base [Exception()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) constructor)

In the arcsin case, the argument thrown would depend on how the function contract is defined. It could be argued that either exception is applicable, but given that the valid range for the input arguments is well defined, these can be made explicit as part of the contract, and invalid arguments rejected via the use of an `IllegalArgumentException`.

The use of an [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) is :

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or
>   inappropriate argument.

Given that it's possible to prevent doing any arithmetic knowing the range of acceptable values in advance, this seems to be the right choice of exception to throw.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a factor of your design in deciding how something should work.  Another option is to throw a custom checked exception, I think as long as your consistent within your package/API, and follow your established coding standards if you have any, you'll be fine.  I think either is a valid choice among those two, I would just make a design decision and document it, so that it is an established decision for future development.  All that said, I would probably pick `IllegalArgumentException` because its an earlier detection of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) seems more valid of the two. It tells me that I've done something wrong (I.E. passed invalid arguments) whereas [`ArithmeticException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) implies that the application was incapable of performing the arithmetic but gives no clues as to why.